# how to return to the invoke action in struts2

Tags: java, redirect, struts2

I'm using struts 2, and I have a, b, c, d four action now. There's a link `"mobile view"` in all of the four pages, if click the link, it will go to `mobileCheck action` to set the session.
So after executing mobileCheck action, I want to return to the invoke action like

```
1. click link in action a ==>mobileCheck action ==> return to a.action

2. click link in action b ==>mobileCheck action ==> return to b.action

3. click link in action c ==>mobileCheck action ==> return to c.action

4. click link in action d ==>mobileCheck action ==> return to d.action
```

there're dozens of actions like this in my project, 
is there any variable to set, What should I do, thanks a lot.

Comment: If mobileCheck action does not render a view but simply redirects back to *.action then, the logic would best belong in an interceptor. With that done you can apply the interceptor stack to all your actions and the problem is nicely solved. With this method you would implement a class ("MobileCheckInterceptor") edit a few lines in struts.xml and your dozens of actions could remain perfectly free of change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of this Actions have the same business in common, then a ***better design would be making each Action extending MobileCheck action***.

Modify MobileCheck Action to do the business in a `public String mobileView()` method (instead of execute);

Modify Actions A,B,C,D to extend it (`public class ActionA extends MobileCheck` ), with their business in `execute()`;

Finally, make the `mobileView()` method returning `execute()`: it will return the `execute()` method of the Action you are running:

```
public class MobileCheck extends ActionSupport {
    public String execute() throws Exception{
        log.debug("MobileCheck execute() should never be invoked");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String mobileView() throws Exception{
        // do something
        log.debug("mobileView() business performed");
        return execute(); /* THIS IS THE TRICK */ 
    }
}

public class ActionA extends MobileCheck {
    public String execute() throws Exception{
        // do something
        log.debug("ActionA execute() is invoked");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

public class ActionB extends MobileCheck {
    public String execute() throws Exception{
        // do something
        log.debug("ActionB execute() is invoked");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

a.jsp

```
<s:form>
    <s:submit method="mobileView" action="actionA" 
                      value="call mobileView() and re-execute Action A" />
</s:form>
```

b.jsp

```
<s:form>
    <s:submit method="mobileView" action="actionB" 
                      value="call mobileView() and re-execute Action B" />
</s:form>
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="actionA" class="foo.bar.ActionA">
    <result>a.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="actionB" class="foo.bar.ActionB">
    <result>b.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**KISS paradigm For The Win**

Comment: You can use also the `method` parameter in the `struts.xml` declaration for each `action` if you want to put all the methods in the same class, so you can save code.

Comment: I prefer many little classes than a big one, for readability and code maintenance... but this depends on the type and the size of the operations performed, if ActionA and ActionB business is like "order something ascending" and "order something descending", then they can stay in the same Action... if they instead executes very different logical operations, I prefer to use different Actions

Comment: Hi @AndreaLigios, the problem is the link in a, b, c, d action is a common jsp, this link <a> is one item of the navigator --- "view Full Site", so in every page clicking this link, I want to change a session value(that's what I want to do in 'mobileCheck action'), and not show mobile css class base on that, so here probably can't use different action name in each jsp

Comment: If the "navigator bar" is inside a form, the link (or the submit button) is the same, only the `action` attribute of the form will change; by the way you can populate that dynamically in the same way from the Actions: the navigator is still the same, but the <a> is read from the Action and is different based on the JSP where it is placed

Comment: Feel free to edit your description adding the new details in a cleaner way, to get further help

Comment: Hi @AndreaLigios, I took your example and make some changes, then solved my problem, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this, I save the url in the session, and in the action class, get this session value to **nextURL** variable, and action result will use this variable **${nextURL}** for redirection.

1) In every a, b, c, d jsp, it include the same code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<s:url action="viewFullSite.action" namespace="" />" id="viewFullSite">View Full Site</a></li>
</ul>
```

and save the current page uri:

```
HttpServletRequest req = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    String uri = "";
    String paramString = "";
    if(ServletActionContext.getActionMapping()!=null){
        String namespace = ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getNamespace();
        String action = ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getName();
        uri = namespace + "/" + action + ".action";
        if (req.getQueryString() != null){
            paramString = "?" + req.getQueryString();
            uri += paramString;
        }   
        req.getSession().setAttribute(RequestParam.invoke_uri.toString(), uri);
    }
```

2) in the xml:

```
<action name="viewFullSite" class="tlc.ui.action.MobileOrFullViewSwitch" method="switchFullSiteView">
        <result name="success_nextURL" type="redirect">${nextURL}</result>
    </action>
```

3) in the action class:

```
public class MobileOrFullViewSwitch  extends TLCAction {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerManager.getLogger(Account.class);
private String nextURL = "";

public String switchFullSiteView(){
    request.getSession().setAttribute(SessionConstants.IGNORE_MOBILEVIEW, "true");
    // set the nextURL property if it was specified
    this.nextURL = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute(RequestParam.invoke_uri.toString());
    if (this.nextURL == null) this.nextURL = "";

    // security check: only support relative URLs; anything else is ignored
    if (!this.nextURL.startsWith("/")) this.nextURL = "";

    if (isEmpty(this.nextURL)) {
        this.nextURL = "/home.action";
    }
    return ResultCode.SUCCESS_NEXT_URL;
}

public String switchMobileView(){
    return ResultCode.SUCCESS_NEXT_URL;
}
public String getNextURL() {
    return nextURL;
}
```

}

it works, but if there's any way more easy to implement, please point out. thanks.